# Clickable content in a VuetifyJs Tooltip

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using **VuetifyJS** in a **VueJS** application I am developing and am having issues making the content within a tooltip clickable. Even if I adjust the opacity of the tooltip popup, clicking on the tooltip content still passes the click event to the element below the tooltip.

How can I make the content within the tooltip clickable?

https://codepen.io/deftonez4me/pen/mdRwozq

```
    <v-btn @click.stop="topicItem.editTime = !topicItem.editTime" icon x-small>
          <v-icon>mdi-clock-time-three-outline</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    
    <v-tooltip v-model="topicItem.editTime" top color="primary" title="Click to Edit Time Allotted" :open-on-hover="false" :z-index="9999">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <span><!-- 00 --></span>
      </template>

      <v-time-picker
        format="24hr"
        use-seconds
      ></v-time-picker>
    </v-tooltip>
```

Comment: why do you put a entire time-picker inside your tooltip?

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/Denizzer/pen/GRrELJG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you're trying to also trigger the tooltip using an external button.

Containing an entire time picker like this isn't the intended use-case of a tooltip. A tooltip is mostly to provide text clues to a component's meaning/functionality.

The reason this doesn't work is because the tooltip parent wraps the `v-time-picker` and prevents you from clicking through it to the clock. If you use inspect element, you will see a tooltip div completely covering the time picker component.

For this use case, you'd be better to use a `v-menu` as a popover.

You could use an `activator` slot or alternatively bind it to an external button using `v-model` or `value`.

This way you can have the `v-time-picker` pop out like a tooltip but also have its contents clickable.

You can find more information from the [popover section of the menu component in Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#popover-menu)